# executable fails to create a new file on double click execution

Tags: c++, macos, fstream

I'm writing a program that creates a new text file upon execution. Nothing too complicated.
After compiling the program, I have noticed it creates a new file as expected when executed using terminal, but fails to create a new file using double click execution.
Here is a sample of  the code i'm using:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outputFile("NewFile.txt");
    outputFile << "Some text";
    outputFile.close();
    printf("File created successfully!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It creates the file relative to the present working directory. You can probably specify the desired present working directory when you define the icon/button for the application. Alternatively, specify an absolute path in the code.

Comment: @jogojapan In that case, what is the present working directory when executing using double click? Shouldn't it be the same directory?

Comment: I not very familiar with OS X, but there are many related questions: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=stackoverflow+os+x+default+working+directory+for+applications&oq=stackoverflow+os+x+default+working+directory+for+applications Perhaps some of the help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in the following way:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    // dirsep is a pointer to the file name
    char *dirsep = strrchr( argv[0], '/' );
    // If it's not null, set the value to 0, seperating the directory
    // from the file name
    if( dirsep != NULL ) *dirsep = 0;

    // Change the current working directory to the path of the executable
    if(chdir(argv[0]) != 0) printf("The file will be created in the home directory");

    ofstream outputFile("NewFile.txt");
    outputFile << "Some text";
    outputFile.close();
    printf("File created successfully!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks to @jogojapan from pointing me in the right direction.